# Dots, subsections in beamer

Tags: beamer, header-footer, navigation, mini-frames

```
\section{Results}

\subsection{}

\frame 
{ 
\frametitle{Example 1} 
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\begin{itemize}
\pause \itemi  example 1 say
\end{itemize}
} 


\frame 
{ 
%\frametitle{Example 1} 

\begin {figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{figureK-Fixed.eps}
\label{figureK-Fixed}
\end{figure}
}
```

While I do it, the second frame appears as a new dot in the header.
How can I make just the first one appear?
Can I close a subsection?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: @Felipe if you explain what you need better I am sure someone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 6):

Including the OP's code snippet in a working example  results in two frames with the same title (if one uncomments the second `\frametitle`). The first frame contains two slides (a list with one item which is uncovered on the second slide), the second frame contains a graphics. As there are two frames, there are two "dot" entries in the header (assuming, e.g., the `miniframes` outer theme).

I guess the OP wants *one* frame with three slides, and the list to be *replaced* with the graphics on the third slide. This can be achieved using the `overprint` environment and the `\onslide` command.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme{miniframes}

\begin{document}

\section{Results}

\subsection{}

\begin{frame}{Example 1}

\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\begin{overprint}

\onslide<1-2>
\begin{itemize}
\item<2>  example 1 say
\end{itemize}

\onslide<3>
\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}

\end{figure}

\end{overprint}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```